# It has been long time since

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

I want to use this sentence, but I am not sure whether or not it is correct.

My sentence is:

> "It has been a long time since we are working on the same topic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the sentence is fine, but the second part sounds bad. basically, you're describing a finished action in the past, and a non finished action since then (has been). so the second part should be expressed with the past simple tense:

"It has been a long time since we worked on the same topic".

As usual, note that in the spoken language, "it has been" will be contracted to just "it's been".

Answer (score 1):

One way of writing the sentence would be,

> It has been a long time since we have been working on the same topic.

Hope this is what you meant to say and the answer helps!